# How to embed the SoundCloud player in Android?

Tags: android, api, android-mediaplayer, soundcloud

I want to embed the SoundCloud player to play SoundCloud URL in my android app.

I had tried to use SoundCloud Java API wrapper. But that thing is giving me an error when I try to get the track:

This line causes the error

```
 HttpResponse trackResp = wrapper.get(Request.to("/tracks/60913196"));
```

> Error - 13781-13781/ com.example.DDS.soundcloud E/Trace﹕ error opening
>   trace file: No such file or directory (2)

If anyone is having the working project of Soundcloud player in an android app. I request you to please share the project.

**This is my present code.**

```
String id = getResources().getString(R.string.sc_client_id);
String secret = getResources().getString(R.string.sc_client_secret);
ApiWrapper wrapper = new ApiWrapper(id,secret, null, null);

try {
    //Only needed for user-specific actions;
    //wrapper.login("<user>", "<pass>");
    //HttpResponse resp = wrapper.get(Request.to("/me"));
    //Get a track
    HttpResponse trackResp = wrapper.get(Request.to("/tracks/60913196"));
    //Track JSON response OK?
    if(trackResp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
    {
        JSONObject trackJSON = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(trackResp.getEntity()));
        //If track is streamable, fetch the stream URL (mp3-https) and start the MediaPlayer
        if(trackJSON.getBoolean("streamable"))
        {
            HttpResponse streamResp = wrapper.get(Request.to("/tracks/60913196/stream"));
            JSONObject streamJSON = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(streamResp.getEntity()));
            String streamurl = streamJSON.getString("location");
            Log.i("SoundCloud", trackJSON.getString("streamable"));
            Log.i("SoundCloud", streamurl);
            m_soundcloudPlayer.stop();
            m_soundcloudPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            m_soundcloudPlayer.setDataSource(streamurl);
            m_soundcloudPlayer.prepare();
            m_soundcloudPlayer.start();
        }

    }
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch (ParseException e)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (JSONException e)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily play the HTML5 Player of SoundCloud in WebView, all you need to do are following.

//In Activity_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">
        <WebView android:id="@+id/webview"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     />

    </LinearLayout>
```

// In ActivityClass.java

```
mSoundCloudPlayer =(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

String VIDEO_URL = "Set Your Embedded URL";

String html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html> <head> <meta charset=\"UTF-8\"><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"target-densitydpi=high-dpi\" /> <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\"> <link rel=\"stylesheet\" media=\"screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:1.5)\" href=\"hdpi.css\" /></head> <body style=\"background:black;margin:0 0 0 0; padding:0 0 0 0;\"> <iframe id=\"sc-widget " +
                                "\" width=\"100%\" height=\"50%\"" + // Set Appropriate Width and Height that you want for SoundCloud Player
                                " src=\"" + VIDEO_URL   // Set Embedded url
                                + "\" frameborder=\"no\" scrolling=\"no\"></iframe>" +
                                "<script src=\"https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script> </body> </html> ";

        mSoundCloudPlayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mSoundCloudPlayer.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mSoundCloudPlayer.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mSoundCloudPlayer.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mSoundCloudPlayer.loadDataWithBaseURL("",html,"text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Comment: Could you also add an explanation?

Comment: I have added an explanation.

Comment: What if I got just A url from Soundcloud i.e https://soundcloud.com/alimaya/deep-relaxation-guided.
How do I play this specific url song in embedded player?

Comment: try to set the VIDEO_URL variable with your url and run this code, i think it should run.